# Como separar valores que estão em uma mesma variavel?

Tags: r

Estou usando a função:

`t2 <- t1[, strsplit(DC_DESCRITORES, "|")]`

Para dividir uma variavél:

`t1[, DC_DESCRITORES := c("D001|D004|D005|D006|D007|D008|D009|D010|D012|D014")]`

Mas como eu rodo o codigo, o valor sair:

```
D
0
0
1
|
D
0
0
4
|
D
0
0
5
```

Gostaria de saber, o que posso fazer para que os dados saiam de forma com cada valor entre as "|" em uma varivel. Seria assim:

| V1 | V2 | V3 | V4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D001 | D004 | D005 | D006 |

Comment: Evite agradecer e cumprimentar nas publicações pois aqui no [pt.so] são considerados ruído de comunicação.  Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), [Saudações e Agradecimentos](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/137387) e [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/137387).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Uma sugestão é utilizar a função `str_split()` do `::stringr`.

Primeiro crio o dataset:

```
t1 <- tibble(DC_DESCRITORES = c("D001|D004|D005|D006|D007|D008|D009|D010|D012|D014"))


# A tibble: 1 × 1
  DC_DESCRITORES                                   
  <chr>                                            
1 D001|D004|D005|D006|D007|D008|D009|D010|D012|D014
```

Agora o split:

A função `str_split()` pede:

- a string a ser decomposta;
- o padrão a ser utilizado para decompor a string
- o número de colunas desejado

A string a ser decomposta, é `t1$DC_DESCRITORES`

O padrão de separação é o `"|"`. Nesse caso, precisamos usar o escape. Então a regex do padrão fica `"\\|"`

O número de colunas desejado é 10.
Você pode informar essa valor diretamente no parâmetro `n =` , ou você pode automatizar a definição do número de colunas com a função `str_count()` buscando pelo padrão letra "D". Assim, a função identifica 10 letras "D" na string e considera que devem ser construídas 10 colunas.

O resultado desse processo é uma lista. Se vc quiser que saia uma matriz, é só informar o argumento `simplify = T`

Por fim, converte-se a matriz em *data frame* com as função `as.data.frame()`

```
str_split(t1$DC_DESCRITORES, 
          pattern = "\\|", 
          n = str_count(t1$DC_DESCRITORES, pattern = "D"), 
          simplify = T) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

resultado:

```
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10
1 D001 D004 D005 D006 D007 D008 D009 D010 D012 D014
```

Answer (score 2):

Como está operando em regex, o pipe `|` tem função específica, então utilize a notação `\\` como sequência de escape (duplo dentro do R)

```
library(data.table)
t1 = data.table(a = LETTERS[1:5], b = 1:5)
t1[, DC_DESCRITORES := c("D001|D004|D005")]

t2 <- as.matrix(t1[, strsplit(DC_DESCRITORES, "\\|")])
t2 <- t(t2)
t2 <- data.table(t2)

t2
#     V1   V2   V3
#1: D001 D004 D005
#2: D001 D004 D005
#3: D001 D004 D005
#4: D001 D004 D005
#5: D001 D004 D005
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Como apontado nas outras respostas, porque `|` tem significado reservado em expressões regulares, precisa usar escape (`\`) para indicar que quer o caractere literalmente.
2. Como está usando *data.table*, pode usar `tstrsplit` ("transpose string split") para quebrar por colunas.

```
library(data.table)

# dados de exemplo
t1 <- data.table(DC_DESCRITORES = paste(sprintf("D%03d", 1:5), collapse = "|"))

t1
#>              DC_DESCRITORES
#> 1: D001|D002|D003|D004|D005

t1[, strsplit(DC_DESCRITORES, "\\|")]
#>      V1
#> 1: D001
#> 2: D002
#> 3: D003
#> 4: D004
#> 5: D005

t1[, tstrsplit(DC_DESCRITORES, "\\|")]
#>      V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
#> 1: D001 D002 D003 D004 D005
```

Sem usar *data.table*, pode usar `transpose(strsplit())`:

```
data.frame(transpose(strsplit(t1$DC_DESCRITORES, "\\|")))
#>   X.D001. X.D002. X.D003. X.D004. X.D005.
#> 1    D001    D002    D003    D004    D005
```